# Express JS Serve React JS Site With Path Longer Than Just Subdirectory

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express

I have a React JS website being served by an Express JS Backend. My app has an api to fetch data from a database, and then at the end sends the built website. Here is my index.js in my backend:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const cors = require('cors');

require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();
const frontEndPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'frontend', 'build')

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static(frontEndPath));

app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello from the API!')
})

// Various API Routes From Different Files I Have Omitted

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(frontEndPath, 'index.html'));
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log('Running on port', PORT);
});
```

I am using React-Router-Dom for the pages - here is the Routes:

```
<div className='main'>
    <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Dashboard />} />
        <Route path='/repairs' element={<Repairs />} />
        <Route path='/repairs/repair/:id' element={<Repair />} />
        <Route path='/calendar' element={<Calendar />} />
        <Route path='/customers' element={<Customers />} />
        <Route path='/settings' element={<Settings />} />
    </Routes>
</div>
```

One of the pages of the React site has a parameter in its URL, and it works just fine except when I reload that page or try to get to it directly from the URL. At that stage it doesn't show the usual "Could not get /", and also doesn't show the page I have for an invalid parameter - it just shows completely blank.

I have tried tweaking the /* route and adding a separate route for that page, but haven't had any success. I've probably missed something, but I can't find the answer anywhere.

Comment: "t just shows completely blank" probably there is issue in your react code, check browser console,  it could be due to some logic statement returning empty array or null.
To check where that issue coming,  press `ctrl+u` when you see that blank page, if its showing <html> tag with various <script> tags then there is issue with react not server otherwise its server.